# Select row per group on right table based on a condition SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server: I have two tables, both share a common column `Id`. The first table is grouped by certain columns and for each group there may be multiple rows from second table. But I wanted to select only one row from second table based on a condition
ie., a column in second table can have these 3 values TRUE, FALSE, UNKNOWN, the value should be YES if all rows for a group is 'TRUE' or No if any of the row has FALSE or unknown.

Comment: Can you please show the tables/schema?

Comment: Table1[id varchar, col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 varchar] Table2[id varchar, col2 varchar] select col1,col2 from Table1 group by col1, col2 now the table2 may have multiple rows for each group from above query: the new query should have look at all rows of a group at col2 from table2 and produce YES if all rows of col2 are TRUE else NO

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Table1 (id varchar(10), col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(10) )
create table Table2 (id varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))
go

insert into Table1(Id, col1, col2, col3)
values('a', '1', '2', '3'),
('b', '4', '5', '6'),
('c', '7', '8', '9');

insert into Table2(Id, col2)
values
('a', 'true'), ('a', 'unknown'), ('a', 'false'),
('b', 'true'), ('b', 'true'), ('b', 'true'),
('c', 'true'), ('c', 'true'), ('c', 'false');


--1
select t1.col1, t1.col2, isnull(itr.istrue, 0) as allistrue
from Table1 as t1
outer apply 
(
    select min(1) as istrue
    from Table2 AS t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    group by t2.id
    having min(t2.col2) = max(t2.col2)
    and min(t2.col2) = 'true'
) as itr
group by t1.col1, t1.col2, itr.istrue;


--2
select  src.col1, src.col2, min(allistrue)
from
(
select t1.col1, t1.col2, 
isnull(
(
select 1 
where exists(select * from Table2 AS t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col2 = 'true')
and not exists (select * from Table2 AS t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.col2 <> 'true')
), 0) AS allistrue

from Table1 as t1
) as src
group by src.col1, src.col2;


--3
select t1.col1, t1.col2, case when min(tt.id) is not null then 1 else 0 end as allistrue
from Table1 as t1
left join
(
    select Id
    from Table2
    where col2 = 'true'
    except
    select Id
    from Table2
    where col2 <> 'true'
) AS tt ON t1.id = tt.id
group by t1.col1, t1.col2;
```